# Cloudant query index over map reduce view

Tags: mapreduce, cloudant

I've been using Cloudant Query to find documents and found it works really well.

The documentation says "Cloudant Query indexes can also be built using MapReduce Views".   I cannot see where the index definition syntax allows specifying a view.

Is there an example of an index or query that uses a view?

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](https://docs.cloudant.com/cloudant_query.html) does indeed say that "Cloudant Query indexes can also be built using MapReduce Views" but it is referring to the technology which underpins the Cloudant Query service.

Cloudant Query indexes can take two forms:

- `type: "text"` is an index built on Apache Lucene which is suitable for fielded searches and full-text queries
- `type: "json"` is an index built on MapReduce where materialized views are created to be able to answer the queries you supply

The sentence you refer to in the documentation is intended to convey that Cloudant Query indexes can be specified as `type: "json"` which result the MapReduce views behind the scenes.